# How can I initialise an .each() function only after a specific event happened?

Tags: javascript, events, initialization, each

I have the following function, that zooms out on images once they enter the viewport. All images are lazyloaded, which is why I want to start the zooming behavior only when the image is fully visible. The event to listen to is called 'lazyunveilread'. Then there is a css transition to fade in the image. Once both things are done, the zooming should be initialized.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. I tried installing the event listener on the event but that only works for the first element and not for the others.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', check_if_in_view, {
 capture: true,
 passive: true
});

var $animation_elements = $('.zoom-images');
var $window = $(window);
function check_if_in_view() {
 var window_height = $window.height();
 var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
 var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);
 $animation_elements.each(function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var $zoom = $(this).children('img.zoom');
  var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
  var element_top_position = $element.offset().top; 
  var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height);
  if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
   (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
    if (!$zoom.hasClass('is-zooming')) {
     requestAnimationFrame( function() {
      $zoom.addClass('is-zooming');
     });
    } 
  } else {
   if ($zoom.hasClass('is-zooming')) {
    requestAnimationFrame( function() {
     $zoom.removeClass('is-zooming');
    });
   }
  }
 });
};

/* lazyloading with lazysizes.js */

! function(a, b) {
 var c = b(a, a.document, Date);
 a.lazySizes = c, "object" == typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = c)
}("undefined" != typeof window ? window : {}, function(a, b, c) {
 "use strict";
 var d, e;
 if (function() {
   var b, c = {
    lazyClass: "lazy",
    loadedClass: " is-loaded",
    loadingClass: " is-loading",
    preloadClass: "lazypreload",
    errorClass: "lazyerror",
    autosizesClass: "lazyautosizes",
    srcAttr: "data-src",
    srcsetAttr: "data-srcset",
    sizesAttr: "data-sizes",
    minSize: 40,
    customMedia: {},
    init: !0,
    expFactor: 1.5,
    hFac: .8,
    loadMode: 1,
    loadHidden: 0,
    ricTimeout: 0,
    throttleDelay: 125
   };
   e = a.lazySizesConfig || a.lazysizesConfig || {};
   for (b in c) b in e || (e[b] = c[b])
  }(), !b || !b.getElementsByClassName) return {
  init: function() {},
  cfg: e,
  noSupport: !0
 };
 var f = b.documentElement,
  g = a.HTMLPictureElement,
  h = "addEventListener",
  i = "getAttribute",
  j = a[h].bind(a),
  k = a.setTimeout,
  l = a.requestAnimationFrame || k,
  m = a.requestIdleCallback,
  n = /^picture$/i,
  o = ["load", "error", "lazyincluded", "_lazyloaded"],
  p = {},
  q = Array.prototype.forEach,
  r = function(a, b) {
   return p[b] || (p[b] = new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + b + "(\\s|$)")), p[b].test(a[i]("class") || "") && p[b]
  },
  s = function(a, b) {
   r(a, b) || a.setAttribute("class", (a[i]("class") || "").trim() + " " + b)
  },
  t = function(a, b) {
   var c;
   (c = r(a, b)) && a.setAttribute("class", (a[i]("class") || "").replace(c, ""))
  },
  u = function(a, b, c) {
   var d = c ? h : "removeEventListener";
   c && u(a, b), o.forEach(function(c) {
    a[d](c, b)
   })
  },
  v = function(a, c, e, f, g) {
   var h = b.createEvent("Event");
   return e || (e = {}), e.instance = d, h.initEvent(c, !f, !g), h.detail = e, a.dispatchEvent(h), h
  },
  w = function(b, c) {
   var d;
   !g && (d = a.picturefill || e.pf) ? (c && c.src && !b[i]("srcset") && b.setAttribute("srcset", c.src), d({
    reevaluate: !0,
    elements: [b]
   })) : c && c.src && (b.src = c.src)
  },
  x = function(a, b) {
   return (getComputedStyle(a, null) || {})[b]
  },
  y = function(a, b, c) {
   for (c = c || a.offsetWidth; c < e.minSize && b && !a._lazysizesWidth;) c = b.offsetWidth, b = b.parentNode;
   return c
  },
  z = function() {
   var a, c, d = [],
    e = [],
    f = d,
    g = function() {
     var b = f;
     for (f = d.length ? e : d, a = !0, c = !1; b.length;) b.shift()();
     a = !1
    },
    h = function(d, e) {
     a && !e ? d.apply(this, arguments) : (f.push(d), c || (c = !0, (b.hidden ? k : l)(g)))
    };
   return h._lsFlush = g, h
  }(),
  A = function(a, b) {
   return b ? function() {
    z(a)
   } : function() {
    var b = this,
     c = arguments;
    z(function() {
     a.apply(b, c)
    })
   }
  },
  B = function(a) {
   var b, d = 0,
    f = e.throttleDelay,
    g = e.ricTimeout,
    h = function() {
     b = !1, d = c.now(), a()
    },
    i = m && g > 49 ? function() {
     m(h, {
      timeout: g
     }), g !== e.ricTimeout && (g = e.ricTimeout)
    } : A(function() {
     k(h)
    }, !0);
   return function(a) {
    var e;
    (a = !0 === a) && (g = 33), b || (b = !0, e = f - (c.now() - d), e < 0 && (e = 0), a || e < 9 ? i() : k(i, e))
   }
  },
  C = function(a) {
   var b, d, e = 99,
    f = function() {
     b = null, a()
    },
    g = function() {
     var a = c.now() - d;
     a < e ? k(g, e - a) : (m || f)(f)
    };
   return function() {
    d = c.now(), b || (b = k(g, e))
   }
  },
  D = function() {
   var g, m, o, p, y, D, F, G, H, I, J, K, L = /^img$/i,
    M = /^iframe$/i,
    N = "onscroll" in a && !/(gle|ing)bot/.test(navigator.userAgent),
    O = 0,
    P = 0,
    Q = 0,
    R = -1,
    S = function(a) {
     Q--, (!a || Q < 0 || !a.target) && (Q = 0)
    },
    T = function(a) {
     return null == K && (K = "hidden" == x(b.body, "visibility")), K || !("hidden" == x(a.parentNode, "visibility") && "hidden" == x(a, "visibility"))
    },
    U = function(a, c) {
     var d, e = a,
      g = T(a);
     for (G -= c, J += c, H -= c, I += c; g && (e = e.offsetParent) && e != b.body && e != f;)(g = (x(e, "opacity") || 1) > 0) && "visible" != x(e, "overflow") && (d = e.getBoundingClientRect(), g = I > d.left && H < d.right && J > d.top - 1 && G < d.bottom + 1);
     return g
    },
    V = function() {
     var a, c, h, j, k, l, n, o, q, r, s, t, u = d.elements;
     if ((p = e.loadMode) && Q < 8 && (a = u.length)) {
      for (c = 0, R++; c < a; c++)
       if (u[c] && !u[c]._lazyRace)
        if (!N || d.prematureUnveil && d.prematureUnveil(u[c])) ba(u[c]);
        else if ((o = u[c][i]("data-expand")) && (l = 1 * o) || (l = P), r || (r = !e.expand || e.expand < 1 ? f.clientHeight > 500 && f.clientWidth > 500 ? 500 : 370 : e.expand, d._defEx = r, s = r * e.expFactor, t = e.hFac, K = null, P < s && Q < 1 && R > 2 && p > 2 && !b.hidden ? (P = s, R = 0) : P = p > 1 && R > 1 && Q < 6 ? r : O), q !== l && (D = innerWidth + l * t, F = innerHeight + l, n = -1 * l, q = l), h = u[c].getBoundingClientRect(), (J = h.bottom) >= n && (G = h.top) <= F && (I = h.right) >= n * t && (H = h.left) <= D && (J || I || H || G) && (e.loadHidden || T(u[c])) && (m && Q < 3 && !o && (p < 3 || R < 4) || U(u[c], l))) {
       if (ba(u[c]), k = !0, Q > 9) break
      } else !k && m && !j && Q < 4 && R < 4 && p > 2 && (g[0] || e.preloadAfterLoad) && (g[0] || !o && (J || I || H || G || "auto" != u[c][i](e.sizesAttr))) && (j = g[0] || u[c]);
      j && !k && ba(j)
     }
    },
    W = B(V),
    X = function(a) {
     var b = a.target;
     if (b._lazyCache) return void delete b._lazyCache;
     S(a), s(b, e.loadedClass), t(b, e.loadingClass), u(b, Z), v(b, "lazyloaded")
    },
    Y = A(X),
    Z = function(a) {
     Y({
      target: a.target
     })
    },
    $ = function(a, b) {
     try {
      a.contentWindow.location.replace(b)
     } catch (c) {
      a.src = b
     }
    },
    _ = function(a) {
     var b, c = a[i](e.srcsetAttr);
     (b = e.customMedia[a[i]("data-media") || a[i]("media")]) && a.setAttribute("media", b), c && a.setAttribute("srcset", c)
    },
    aa = A(function(a, b, c, d, f) {
     var g, h, j, l, m, p;
     (m = v(a, "lazybeforeunveil", b)).defaultPrevented || (d && (c ? s(a, e.autosizesClass) : a.setAttribute("sizes", d)), h = a[i](e.srcsetAttr), g = a[i](e.srcAttr), f && (j = a.parentNode, l = j && n.test(j.nodeName || "")), p = b.firesLoad || "src" in a && (h || g || l), m = {
      target: a
     }, s(a, e.loadingClass), p && (clearTimeout(o), o = k(S, 2500), u(a, Z, !0)), l && q.call(j.getElementsByTagName("source"), _), h ? a.setAttribute("srcset", h) : g && !l && (M.test(a.nodeName) ? $(a, g) : a.src = g), f && (h || l) && w(a, {
      src: g
     })), a._lazyRace && delete a._lazyRace, t(a, e.lazyClass), z(function() {
      var b = a.complete && a.naturalWidth > 1;
      p && !b || (b && s(a, " is-cached"), X(m), a._lazyCache = !0, k(function() {
       "_lazyCache" in a && delete a._lazyCache
      }, 9)), "lazy" == a.loading && Q--
     }, !0)
    }),
    ba = function(a) {
     if (!a._lazyRace) {
      var b, c = L.test(a.nodeName),
       d = c && (a[i](e.sizesAttr) || a[i]("sizes")),
       f = "auto" == d;
      (!f && m || !c || !a[i]("src") && !a.srcset || a.complete || r(a, e.errorClass) || !r(a, e.lazyClass)) && (b = v(a, "lazyunveilread").detail, f && E.updateElem(a, !0, a.offsetWidth), a._lazyRace = !0, Q++, aa(a, b, f, d, c))
     }
    },
    ca = C(function() {
     e.loadMode = 3, W()
    }),
    da = function() {
     3 == e.loadMode && (e.loadMode = 2), ca()
    },
    ea = function() {
     if (!m) {
      if (c.now() - y < 999) return void k(ea, 999);
      m = !0, e.loadMode = 3, W(), j("scroll", da, !0)
     }
    };
   return {
    _: function() {
     y = c.now(), d.elements = b.getElementsByClassName(e.lazyClass), g = b.getElementsByClassName(e.lazyClass + " " + e.preloadClass), j("scroll", W, !0), j("resize", W, !0), j("pageshow", function(a) {
      if (a.persisted) {
       var c = b.querySelectorAll("." + e.loadingClass);
       c.length && c.forEach && l(function() {
        c.forEach(function(a) {
         a.complete && ba(a)
        })
       })
      }
     }), a.MutationObserver ? new MutationObserver(W).observe(f, {
      childList: !0,
      subtree: !0,
      attributes: !0
     }) : (f[h]("DOMNodeInserted", W, !0), f[h]("DOMAttrModified", W, !0), setInterval(W, 999)), j("hashchange", W, !0), ["focus", "mouseover", "click", "load", "transitionend", "animationend"].forEach(function(a) {
      b[h](a, W, !0)
     }), /d$|^c/.test(b.readyState) ? ea() : (j("load", ea), b[h]("DOMContentLoaded", W), k(ea, 2e4)), d.elements.length ? (V(), z._lsFlush()) : W()
    },
    checkElems: W,
    unveil: ba,
    _aLSL: da
   }
  }(),
  E = function() {
   var a, c = A(function(a, b, c, d) {
     var e, f, g;
     if (a._lazysizesWidth = d, d += "px", a.setAttribute("sizes", d), n.test(b.nodeName || ""))
      for (e = b.getElementsByTagName("source"), f = 0, g = e.length; f < g; f++) e[f].setAttribute("sizes", d);
     c.detail.dataAttr || w(a, c.detail)
    }),
    d = function(a, b, d) {
     var e, f = a.parentNode;
     f && (d = y(a, f, d), e = v(a, "lazybeforesizes", {
      width: d,
      dataAttr: !!b
     }), e.defaultPrevented || (d = e.detail.width) && d !== a._lazysizesWidth && c(a, f, e, d))
    },
    f = function() {
     var b, c = a.length;
     if (c)
      for (b = 0; b < c; b++) d(a[b])
    },
    g = C(f);
   return {
    _: function() {
     a = b.getElementsByClassName(e.autosizesClass), j("resize", g)
    },
    checkElems: g,
    updateElem: d
   }
  }(),
  F = function() {
   !F.i && b.getElementsByClassName && (F.i = !0, E._(), D._())
  };
 return k(function() {
  e.init && F()
 }), d = {
  cfg: e,
  autoSizer: E,
  loader: D,
  init: F,
  uP: w,
  aC: s,
  rC: t,
  hC: r,
  fire: v,
  gW: y,
  rAF: z
 }
});
```

```css
.zoom-images {
 display: block;
  position: relative;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
 z-index: 1;
}

.zoom-images img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 150%;
 height: 150%;
 top: -25%;
 left: -25%;
}

.zoom-images img.is-placeholder {
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
   filter: blur(5px);
 z-index: 1;
}

.zoom-images img.is-real {
 z-index: 2;
 will-change: transform;
}

.zoom-images img.is-real.is-zooming {
 transform: scale(0.67);
   transition: transform 2s ease;
   -o-transition: transform 2s ease;
 -webkit-transition: transform 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: transform 2s ease;
     -ms-transition: transform 2s ease;
}

img.is-real {
 opacity: 0.001;
}

img.is-loaded {
 opacity: 0.999;
 transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
<div class="zoom-images">
  <img class="is-placeholder" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" alt="test">
  <img class="lazy is-real zoom" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg"alt="test">
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using a library for lazy-loading images? Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: I updated the post and included the snippet.

Comment: Thank you sharing the snippet, so just to be clear, you want: 1) Make sure images are loaded 2) Fading effect 3) Zooming effect, right?

Comment: Exactly. The zooming function should only be active once the two other events have happened. But then it should run every time the images enter the viewport.

Comment: Excellent, I'll take a deep look into that, by the way is this the library you are using for [lazyloading images](https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload)? Because [lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) is totally different.

Comment: Thank you so much! The library is this one: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes I corrected it in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed your markup a little bit:

```
<div class="zoom-images">
     <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
     <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
</div>
```

[lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) automatically replaces `lazyload` class with `lazyloaded` class once the image is **loaded**. So we can use that to make our adjustments.
Thanks to `transition-delay`, you don't need to write a lot of JavaScript to achieve what you looking for.
 We are basically setting a transition delay for **high quality** image, so once the image is in view-port and *loaded* we gonna wait for fade effect to finish and then zoom effect will be applied after that.
Also we are toggling between 2 *classes*:
 `fade-on` and `fade-off` for **placeholder** image, and also
`zoom-on` and `zoom-off` for **real (high quality)** image.
 So all together it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sy0vqg5e/

Your markup:

```
<body>
    <div class="images-container">
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-images">
            <img class="lazyload is-real zoom-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" data-src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait.jpg" alt="test" />
            <img class="is-placeholder fade-on" src="http://fabiankleeberger.de/porcelain-frontend/assets/img/portrait-lowres.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Styles:

```
.zoom-images {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
          mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
  z-index: 1;
}

.zoom-images img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  top: -25%;
  left: -25%;
}

.zoom-images .is-placeholder {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.zoom-images .fade-on {
  opacity: 1;
}

.zoom-images .is-real {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
  transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  transition: transform 2s ease, -webkit-transform 2s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
          transition-delay: 1s;
}

.zoom-images .zoom-on {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.zoom-images .fade-off {
  opacity: 0.0001;
}

.zoom-images .zoom-off {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.67) !important;
          transform: scale(0.67) !important;
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', check_if_in_view, {
    capture: true,
    passive: true,
});

var $animation_elements = $('.zoom-images');
var $window = $(window);

function check_if_in_view() {
    var window_height = $window.height();
    var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
    var window_bottom_position = window_top_position + window_height;

    $animation_elements.each(function () {
        var $element = $(this);
        var element_bottom_position = $element.offset().top + $element.outerHeight();

        var placeholder = $element.find('.is-placeholder');
        var real = $element.find('.is-real');

        if (element_bottom_position >= window_top_position && $element.offset().top <= window_bottom_position) {
            console.log(real);
            // When image is in viewport and has been loaded
            if (real.hasClass('lazyloaded')) {
                placeholder.addClass('fade-off');
                real.addClass('zoom-off');
            }
        } else {
            // when image is not in viewport back to starting effects
            placeholder.removeClass('fade-off');
            real.removeClass('zoom-off');
            real.addClass('zoom-on');
        }
    });
}
check_if_in_view()
```